# Is it possible to make a SubItem clickable in a ListView

Tags: c#, listview

i am trying to add two coloumns to a listview one for something and one for something else but  it will not let me select the subitem only the original item is there anyways to fix this without using full row select? I also have to be able to load items from a txt file so datagridview will not work for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `DataGridView` is more suitable for what you're trying to do. Sub items in `ListView` are not meant to be clicked individually.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the ListView of WindowsForms framework you can assign a MouseDown event handler:

```
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Console.Out.WriteLine("e.X = {0}, e.Y={1}", e.X, e.Y);
}
```

Here you has the point where mouse clicked on within ListView control. Now you can compute the column index because you know the width of everey column.

Not very comfortable but a fallback if you do not find another solution.